# SHA256 function behavior in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sha256

When I'm calling the `sha256('abc')` function in Postgres it returns the hash of passed value as `bytea` as the result of that function.

```
SELECT sha256('abc'); -- Works as expected
```

[image: DBeaver execution result]

However, when I have a custom function accepting the `text` as an input parameter and doing the exact same thing within that function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hash_text(input text) RETURNS bytea
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
  res bytea;
BEGIN
  SELECT sha256(input) INTO res;
  RETURN res;
END
$$

-- Executing the function above
SELECT hash_text('abc');
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function sha256(text) does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Where: PL/pgSQL function hash_text(text) line 5 at SQL statement

I looked into official [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-binarystring.html) and it seems like `sha256` is accepting `bytea` as an input parameter. What confuses me is the fact it works when I pass `'abc'` value directly, but doesn't work when that value is coming through the function parameter? The second thing that confuses me is why does it yield different result when I convert `input::bytea` in that function? What am I missing here?

I'm kind of new to Postgres so I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way to do it, but this kind of formatting converted it to `bytea` result I wanted to see. Thanks to @nbk for leading me to this solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hash_text(input text) RETURNS bytea
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
  res bytea;
BEGIN
  SELECT encode(sha256(input::bytea), 'escape')::bytea INTO res;
  RETURN res;
END
$$
```

Answer (score 2):

> What confuses me is the fact it works when I pass 'abc' value directly, but doesn't work when that value is coming through the function parameter?

The literal `'abc'` is of unknown type.  So it looks at how it is used to decide what type it really is. Since it knows that sha256 accepts bytea as input, it treats `'abc'` as being of the type bytea.

In the case of your function, it is not of unknown type.  It is explicitly declared to be of type text.  It will not implicitly convert text to bytea.

> The second thing that confuses me is why does it yield different result when I convert input::bytea in that function?

What different result does it yield?  In my hands, your function with the explicit cast gives the same answer as sha256 does when called directly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. `sha256` has been returning result as `bytea` when it decided on the type of `'abc'` (as you can see from the screenshot in the question) while it was returning the result as `'text'` when I was executing it from the function where I convert the text to `bytea` explicitly. I had to convert the text to `bytea` manually (because that's the behavior I wanted and expected since it worked that way outside of function) and my own answer to this question shows how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to type cast the input

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hash_text(input text) RETURNS text
> LANGUAGE plpgsql
> AS
> $$
> DECLARE
>   res text;
> BEGIN
>   SELECT encode(sha256(input::bytea),  'escape') INTO res;
>   RETURN res;
> END
> $$
>
> -- Executing the function above
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```
>
> ```
> SELECT hash_text('abc');
> ```
>
> ```
> | hash_text                                                                        |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | \272x\277\217\317\352AA@\336]\256"#\260a\243\226z\234\264\377a\362\000\255 |
> ```
>
> ```
> SELECT encode(sha256('abc'),  'escape')
> ```
>
> ```
> | encode                                                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | \272x\277\217\317\352AA@\336]\256"#\260a\243\226z\234\264\377a\362\000\255 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=931e08b4d93ef84bedca3ac798c66e8b)*

Comment: Yea, I tried that out, but it seems to be returning value as hex string while calling sha256('abc') directly returns byte array. How can I achieve the same behavior of calling sha256 with hardcoded text value through the function? I'm also interested in why is it behaving differently?

Comment: it gives bach the same,https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9db89a35dda8a665b6b50404eb9e4f7f  what do you want as result?

Comment: that's interesting, I'm running this same sha256 function on DBeaver on my machine and it's returning `bytea`

Comment: I added the screenshot of the result of that function on my machine and I'd like that same behavior through the function.

Comment: you can convert it like in the changes answer

Comment: Almost there, I'm trying to do exactly the opposite of that. How can enforce the function return the result with the same value of bytea which raw sha256 shows in my DBeaver IDE?

Comment: Ah, I got it.. this was what I needed: `encode(sha256(input::bytea), 'escape')::bytea`. I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to do it, but this yields the expected result.